# ODOO 10 Field many2many no open view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Is there any way to make one field m2m not open when you click on it? When you click on any m2m field, it opens something like a form with the data, but I need the fields that do not open on "quick view".

I tried to use:

`options="{'no_open': True}"`

but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not,if you want to hide some iformation, you can just create an empty embedded form view to hide information.

```
 <field name="field_name">
     <form>
       <group>
          <!-- show some of fields here or keep it empty-->
       </group>
     </form>
 </field>
```

and if you really need this you may want to deal with `javascript` to change the behavior by handling and new option to stop the form from opening.

Comment: I don't really want to hide the information, I just dont want to people do not open the record quick view, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tree open="false" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit':True, 'no_open':True}">
    <field name="nourut" string="No Urut"/>
</tree>
```

add `open="false"` inside field `many2many` tree

Please mark the question as solved.

Comment: What version of Odoo is this for? It does  not work for 15.0.